# Regex to insert characters only twice

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex which works

```
'A12345678912121'.replace(/(.{5})/g,'$1 - ')
```

Output: A1234 - 56789 - 12121 -

Just looking to make it not insert the characters at the end of the string. How do I limit it to only two inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use "look-around" assertions to not replace when at the end of the input.

`'A12345678912121'.replace(/(.{5})(?=.)/g,'$1 - ')
= A1234 - 56789 - 12121`

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thank you, for the link too :)

Comment: Why use a capturing group at all here if you replace with the whole match? Use `.replace(/.{5}(?=.)/g,'$& - ')`